# Dollar sign ($) not escaped in request

Tags: paw-app

When creating a HTTP GET request, adding

```
where={"email":{"$exists":false}}
```

as text in the body results in

```
curl "https://---omitted---" \
     -H 'X-Parse-Application-Id: ---omitted---' \
     -H 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ---omitted---' \
     -H 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' \
     -d "where={\"email\":{\"$exists\":false}}"
```

This request completes with `200 OK` but does not return the expected results. My best guess is that `$exists` keyword is misinterpreted, as the `$` is not escaped and even shows up red in the cURL preview.

When testing with cURL directly, and escaping the keyword, everything works.

If I add a backwards slash (`\`) before the `$`, that results in `\\$` which doesn't help.

How an I escape the `$`? URL-Encode doesn't help, and I couldn't find anything else in your documentation.

Cheers, keep up the good work.

Comment: Nobody here from Paw to answer this? Or did I miss something and the answer is obvious?